# combine two values of an array in php

Tags: php

I have selected two colum of the database as below

```
$sort_query = "SELECT s_uniqid, mar_total FROM record WHERE $x='$y'";
    $run_sort = mysql_query($sort_query);
    while($sort_marks = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_sort))
    {
        foreach($sort_marks as $key => $marks)
        {
            print_r ($marks);
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

I am getting the result as

```
1000001
252
1000002
257
1000003
232
1000004
180
1000005
205
1000006
189
1000007
219
1000008
201
```

I want to make a new array with the element where key as 1000001, 1000002, 1000003 , 1000004  and value is 252,257,232,180 and so on. Please suggest anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
while($sort_marks = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_sort))
{
    $arr[$sort_marks['s_uniqid']] = $sort_marks['mar_total'];
}
```

If you have read the documentation for [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc), this should be self-explanatory. Column `s_uniqid` is used for the keys, and column `mar_total` is used for the values.